# Not getting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: python, linux

I am amending an existing script in which I want to check the set of libraries used in an executable with the shared libraries called at the run time. I have the list of libraries which I need to compare with the shared libraries. For getting shared libraries I am trying to get LD_LIBRARY_PATH by giving below code but I had no luck. I tried checking the variable on command line by giving

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and it returned `/opt/cray/csa/3.0.0-1_2.0501.47112.1.91.ari/lib64:/opt/cray/job/1.5.5-0.1_2.0501.48066.2.43.ari/lib64`

the things that I have already tried are (this is a python script)

```
#! /usr/bin/python -E
import os
    ld_lib_path = os.environ.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
    #ld_lib_path = os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]
```

Comment: How was `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set? Was it `export`-ed in the shell?

Comment: Show us the output of LD_LIBRARY_PATH from 'env'

Comment: I have done nothing to LD_LIBRARY_PATH it should be what it is by default. I tried running a separate script and worked but not in my original script.
#! /usr/bin/python -E
import os
ld_lib_path = os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]
print ld_lib_path

Comment: this is the part of the output from 'env'BUILD_OPTS=/opt/cray/craype/1.05/bin/build-opts
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/jre
USER=kagrawa1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/cray/csa/3.0.0-1_2.0501.47112.1.91.ari/lib64:/opt/cray/job/                                                                                        1.5.5-0.1_2.0501.48066.2.43.ari/lib64

Comment: Does this command work?:

python -c 'import os; temp=os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"); print temp'

Comment: Yes this works, kagrawa1@xxxxx:~/namd_2.9_cle5.0_gnu4.8.2_dynamically_linked> python -c 'import os; temp=os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"); print temp'
/opt/cray/csa/3.0.0-1_2.0501.47112.1.91.ari/lib64:/opt/cray/job/1.5.5-0.1_2.0501.48066.2.43.ari/lib64

Comment: So everything works then right? You should be able to throw a print in your script and it should work?

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what I am doing and this is why it seems so trivial to me. Does giving sys.path at start of the script will making any difference. I am not sure about this but it is present in the original script "sys.path = ['', '/usr/lib/python24.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.4', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/Numeric', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/dbus', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0']"

Comment: sys.path is the location where the script will search for modules. It doesn't affect the ld path

Comment: Very odd. Is there any chance that `/usr/bin/python` might be a shell (or other) wrapper that's setting (or `unset`ting) `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing a print in your script? This works for me from the command line:

```
python -c 'import os; temp=os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"); print temp'
```

script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python -E
import os
ld_lib_path = os.environ.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
print ld_lib_path
```

Comment: thanks Matt, but even I am surprised as this is not working in my original script. I tried it the way you have shown by giving prints all over the script its just not getting variable in the original script.